# How to speed up an algorithm to detect lights that cover a point?

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, optimization, big-o

"Assume you have a road (or numberline) with lights over head that light up a section of the numberline. Lights are represented by a 2D array where the light at index i covers from arr[i][0] to arr[i][1] (inclusive).

You are also given a list of points on this line, and for each point, you want to compute how many lights illuminate that point. I want to return a list where list[i] = the number of lights that illuminate point i."

Sample input/output: `lights = [[1, 7], [5, 11], [7, 9]], points = [7, 1, 5]` should return `[3, 1, 2]`
I wrote a solution where for each point in points, you loop over the lights array and see how many have lights[i][0] <= point <= lights[i][1]. This solution is too slow (being O(n *k) where n = num. lights and k = num. points). I also tried sorting the lamps and breaking when lamp[i][0] > point, but it still times out. Can anyone think of a faster algorithm to compute this array? I'm stumped on how else to approach this.

Comment: Did you try binary search on the sorted array? You might need to do a separate search for the front and back end of the lighted area, but the second one at least has a good starting location.

Comment: hint:  if you just used the array of light info, could you make a data structure for the turn-ons/turn-offs (the basis of a "running total")?  Then traverse that, which would be O(n + k)...

Comment: Probably need a bit more information.  Is the list of lights static? If it is, you could pre-compute the lights for each point and then do a look up.  Are both lists sorted?  If so, you could trim the search window to just include lights and points that potentially intersect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is better solved like this:

- Get all the changes from the lights array and create an array that has twice its size. It will have tuples of point and light-change. The light change component is +1 or -1, depending on whether that point represents the *beginning* of the light span or *end* of it. When it is the end, the point should be one more than found in the lights array, so to indicate that point is still reached by the light, and we should only discount it when moving to the right to the next point.
- Sort this result by point. There might be duplicates.
- Then accumulate from left to right the light-change values, so adding up all those -1 and +1 from left to right, and storing the intermediate results again with the point where the light-change was found. The final accumulated value will of course be 0.
- Optionally make that array unique by point, only keeping the right most of the duplicate points, as those have the right accumulated value to go with it. (I did not do that in below implementation)
- Finally use binary search on that array to translate each given point to the number of lights that shine on that point.

#### Implementation:

```py
from bisect import bisect

def solve(lights, points):
    pairs = sorted((x + i, -i or 1) for changes in lights for i, x in enumerate(changes))
    offsets, changes = zip(*pairs)
    total = 0
    cumul = [0] + [total := total + change for change in changes]
    return [cumul[bisect(offsets, x)] for x in points]

lights = [[1, 7], [5, 11], [7, 9]]
points = [7, 1, 5]
print(solve(lights, points))  # [3, 1, 2]
```

And here is the version that removes duplicates. It is only of benefit if there really are many duplicate offsets in the `cumul` list:

```
def solve(lights, points):
    pairs = sorted((x + i, -i or 1) for changes in lights for i, x in enumerate(changes))
    total = 0
    cumulpairs = [(x, total := total + change) for x, change in pairs]
    # remove duplicates - assuming Python 3.7+ with ordered dicts
    offsets, cumul = zip(*dict(cumulpairs).items())
    cumul = [0] + list(cumul)
    return [cumul[bisect(offsets, x)] for x in points]
```

Comment: I don't quite understand.
1. Won't the size of delta need to be `2 * len(lights) + 1` since it creates 2 elements per 1 element in `lights`? 
2. Why are we decreasing `delta[x2]` by 1? (The indices are inclusive)
3. What if one of the points is between some x1 and x2, and not exactly at one of those?
4. Could you explain the overall logic in a bit more detail? I feel like I'm missing something

Comment: Yes, I misunderstood what exactly was queried in your description. I updated my answer a bit. I am not going to give a full implementation, as for that I would like first to see your question updated with examples of input and expected output, and with your attempt at coding it, and what the problem is with it.

Comment: The former solution you mentioned is unfortunately too slow for large light inputs. What do you mean by "build an array with point values, and then sort it"?

Comment: I see you have not included the information I asked for yet. Are you planning to do so?

Comment: sample input/output added, I didn't try writing up your original proposed solution as I am certain it will time out.

Comment: What is the programming language? Please do show your efforts though.

Comment: I use Python but the language doesn't really matter, looking for a high level explanation of an algorithm, not necessarily an implementation.

Comment: OK, I have updated my answer based on this information.